# LARAVEL v9.23.0 plugin v0.5.3

Tags: breeze, laravel-9

[image]

I'm getting this error when installing Breeze

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: I want to use laravel ui breeze authentication for a project in Laravel 9. When I run npm run dev(i.e after i have done composer require laravel/ui, php artisan ui bootstrap --auth and npm install), it loads and stops where this code snippet stops and doesn't go forward or backward

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Laravel authentication? If `npm run dev` doesn't start, you can try the following tricks.

If you have already done the following comments eg:

1. `composer require laravel/ui`
2. `php artisan UI bootstrap --auth`
3. `npm install`

   Then you can continue with just one more comment. Because this comment just happened to me.
4. `npm run build`

Comment: thanks brother. Allah razı olsun

Comment: This answer specified a command as `composer requires`, I think it should be `composer require` - please edit again if required.